# Querying all items that are in a many-to-many relationship with a child of an object

Tags: python, django

I have the following Django models setup:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    value=models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class Article(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    articles = models.ManyToManyField(Article)
```

I wanted to add an 'images' property to the Publication model. I have implemented it like this

```
@property
def images(self):
    images = []
    for article in self.article_set.all():
        images += list(article.images.all())
    return list(set(images))
```

This works. I also considered trying something like

```
return Images.objects.filter(articles__publication=self)
```

But I don't think that I can do this because then I have to define Images above Publications, which won't work with Articles and Images.

Is there a way for me to improve this query to handle less of the filtering in application logic and more of it in the database?

Comment: Please edit your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I also considered trying something like
>
> ```
> return Images.objects.filter(articles__publication=self)
> ```
>
> But I don't think that I can do this because then I have to define `Images` above
> `Publications`, which won't work with `Articles` and `Images`.

Did you try this?  It seems like it would work and would be the best approach.  You could add a `.distinct()` clause at the end of the query to avoid converting to a set.

It is best practice to set the `related_name` and `related_query_name` variables on your model related fields.  This will make your queries less verbose; `article_set` and `image_set` become `articles` and `images`, respectively.  See example below

```
class Article(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    publication = models.ForeignKey(to=Publication,
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    related_name='articles',
                                    related_query_name='article')


class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    articles = models.ManyToManyField(to=Article,
                                      related_name='images',
                                      related_query_name='image')
```

Look at the [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) documentation.  You are querying the db for every image set on each article.

```
@property
def images(self):
    images = []
    for article in self.article_set.all():
        images += list(article.images.all())
    return list(set(images))
```

Using `prefetch_related`:

```
@property
def images(self):
    images = []
    publication = self.objects.prefetch_related('articles__images')
    for article in publication.articles.all():
        for image in article.images.all():
            images.append(image)

    return set(images)
```